# iPhone SDK: How to solve Tab bar controller with Six Tab

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

i add tab bar controller with six tab view

first four tab view are opening well,  and remaining two view opening in five tab with table view consist five view and six view, on clicking on table view's first cell(five view) that moves to detail view, its also good

my problem When i moving to detail view (five and six view's) there is EDIT button on the TOP of Detail view (five view)
**When we click on the EDIT button, we moves to new Black color view with small icon of six view, From that i am not able to Get Out**

when i open next time also that black color view (six small icons with six view names) opening, **i am not able to come out of that view, once enter into that screen**

can you tell me, how to solve this

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here mainTabBarViewController is UITabBarViewController;

mainTabBarViewController.customizableViewControllers = nil; //it is used to hide the default edit button of the tab bar view controller

Answer (score 0):

That is configure view.It has "Done" button by default on the navigation bar.If you click on the "Done" button, the configure view gets dismissed automatically.

All the best.

Comment: hi Warrior, defaultly I did not get "Done" button, Please tell me and give ur suggestion to me, to solve this problem

Comment: Done button will come by default.Can you put screen-shot and code for creating the tabbar